# Delayed kernel panic in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, remote-access, panic

For our tests we need to trigger kernel panic on a remote server (VM), via SSH:

```
ssh server "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger"
```

The problem is that in most cases the SSH session gets stuck, since the kernel panic happens before the connection is disconnected. There is a generic connection timeout, but this is not good enough.

**Is there a way to delay the panic?**

We tried to put the following in a file on the server:

```
# - panic.sh -

#/bin/bash
sleep 5
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

And then to execute it:

```
ssh server "nohup panic.sh &"
```

But this didn't help. The SSH session waits till the sleep ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your script keeps all pipes open, so `ssh` has to wait to see if you'll write more.

If you close them all, `ssh` knows it won't receive any more output and will exit:

```
$ time ssh localhost 'sleep 5 < /dev/null > log 2>&1 &'
real    0m0.171s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.003s
```

You can also do this from within the script using the `exec` command before the sleep:

```
exec < /dev/null > log 2>&1
```

Comment: Just wondering, would `ssh -T server "echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger"` be sufficient? Does no pseudo-terminal mean there is no pipe back to the local host?

Comment: There's already no pty, which is why you get pipes instead of a terminal. You could technically do the opposite though: request a pty to make `nohup` redirect away from it with `ssh -t localhost 'nohup sleep 5 &'`. This is less explicit and more noisy though

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I played with redirection as well, but couldn't find the right combination. Used `exec < /dev/null > log 2>&1` inside the script